sampleRegions function returning an empty FeatureCollection
I first start by loading in Sentinel-2 data, filtering the date, and taking the median to produce a single image
COPERNICUS = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")

start_date = '2017-04-01'
end_date = '2017-12-31'
COPERNICUS = COPERNICUS.filterDate(start_date, end_date)

composite = COPERNICUS.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())

I then take two pandas dataframes for village data, specifically their coordinates and whether they are damaged or not, and convert them into a feature collection
no_damage = ee.FeatureCollection(undamaged_villages.apply(lambda x: ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([x['LONG_DD'], x['LAT_DD']]), {'STATUS': 'NO DAMAGE'}), axis=1).tolist())

damaged = ee.FeatureCollection(damaged_villages.apply(lambda x: ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([x['LONG_DD'], x['LAT_DD']]), {'STATUS': 'DAMAGED'}), axis=1).tolist())

villages = ee.FeatureCollection([no_damage, damaged]).flatten()

But when I attempt to use the sampleRegions function I get an empty feature collection
bands = ['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 'B5_median', 'B6_median', 'B7_median', 'B8_median', 'B8A_median', 'B11_median', 'B12_median']
property = 'STATUS'

training = composite.select(bands).sampleRegions(
    collection = villages,
    properties = ['STATUS'],
    scale = 10,
    geometries = True
)


This is the output I get when I call training.getInfo()
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'columns': {},
 'properties': {'band_order': ['B2_median',
   'B3_median',
   'B4_median',
   'B5_median',
   'B6_median',
   'B7_median',
   'B8_median',
   'B8A_median',
   'B11_median',
   'B12_median']},
 'features': []}



Chances are that you have no imagery in your AOI for that date-range, as L2 coverage is not global (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR_HARMONIZED#description). Try the same script using COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED instead to verify.
